# cannot get socket.io-emitter to work with socket.io-redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, socket.io, node-redis

i have a pretty simple code, trying to emit from an external process into a socket.io server.

server.js

```
var io = require('socket.io')(3201);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("test 1");
  socket.on('testemit', function (data) {
      console.log("test 2");
      console.log(data);
  });
});
```

the client, emit.js (as found in the docs):

```
var io = require('socket.io-emitter')({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379 });
setInterval(function(){
      io.emit('testemit', {a: 'aaa'});
}, 3000);
```

on the server side, if i run it with

```
 DEBUG=* node server.js
```

all i get is:

```
socket.io:server initializing namespace / +0ms
  socket.io:server creating http server and binding to 3201 +3ms
  socket.io:server creating engine.io instance with opts {"path":"/socket.io"} +1ms
  socket.io:server attaching client serving req handler +2ms
  socket.io-parser encoding packet  aaa {"type":2,"data":["testemit",{"a":"aaa"}],"nsp":"/"} +0ms
  socket.io-parser encoded {"type":2,"data":["testemit",{"a":"aaa"}],"nsp":"/"} as 2["testemit",{"a":"aaa"}] +1ms
```

but the callback in for testemit does not get called at all.

what am i missing?

Comment: emit.js is ran on the same server with "node emit.js"

Comment: i completely misunderstood this. all works. the emit does an emit to all the socket.io clients of this socket.io server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i completely misunderstood this. all works.

the emit does an emit to all the socket.io clients of this socket.io server.

so in the browser it works, like this:

```
        _socket = io.connect(url);
        _socket.on('testemit', function (message) {
            console.log('testemit');
            console.log(message);
        });
```

i am wrongly expecting it to work in the server too.

Comment: I had the same misunderstanding, I thought the events would be received by the server 'socket.io-redis', but no it doesn't work that way...they are received by the client connected to the server that runs socket.io-redis..